# How to save/read mappings within struct?

Tags: storage, mapping, struct, memory

I am trying to create a mapping inside struct and then create a mapping of the struct. Take a look at below example:

```
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Each Level related details are stored using `Level` struct
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    struct Level{
        address payable luckyDraw;
        uint256 dividend;
        address payable topHolder;
        uint256 topInvestment;
        uint256 reversedAllowed;
        mapping(address => uint256) userReversed;
        mapping (uint => address payable) levelUsers;
        uint256 ETH_REVERSED;
        uint256 countDeposit;
        uint totalBuyers;
    }

mapping (uint => Level) public payouts;                    // keeps record of each payout
```

Now here, the payouts saves record of the Level(struct), you can see the struct which have two mapping as well other than other member variables.

When I try to read the payouts, I can never read about these mappings, also it seems that I can never save any record inside these mappings. I am trying to save data for levelUsers but it doesn't seems to work, If I try to read this, it returns me 0x0000.

```
 // add the purchaser address to the all users array
 payouts[1].levelUsers[0] = msg.sender;

address payable user = payouts[1].levelUsers[0];
```

**The user is always 0x000**, seems it never saves successfully

Are my declarations all good?

Comment: Please elaborate on `it doesn't seems to work` (how do you determine that, what error do you get, etc).

Comment: edited. please read thanks for ur time

Comment: How do you determine that `The user is always 0x000`?

Comment: Because I am saving the user like this and then reading accounts information from compiler. accounts[user].luckyDrawWinning = 10; So, in accounts mapping when I enter the address of user the luckDrawWinning is always zero.

Comment: mapping(address => Account) accounts;  struct Account{ uint luckyDrawWinning;}

Comment: Your description in the comment is very hard to read. Please consider adding it properly into your question. Also, the statement `reading accounts information from compiler` doesn't make any sense. The compiler cannot be used during runtime in order to read data from the blockchain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106236/discussion-between-fariha-abbasi-and-goodvibration).